# Custom sap.ui.core.messagebundle texts

Tags: internationalization, sapui5

How can we use custom translations for sap.ui.core.messagebundle? We'd like to provide our own validation messages (e.g., for `String.Search`)?

Answer (score 0):

```
var oBundle;
defaultLocale = "en-EN";
var countryLocale = "de-FR";
oBundle= jQuery.sap.resources({url : "i18n/labels-en.properties", locale: defaultLocale});
//If need to use any other language have a condition to define accordingly.
//oBundle= jQuery.sap.resources({url :"i18n/labels-fr.properties", locale: countryLocale });
```

And in your controls just below to **`setText`**

```
oBundle.getText("label.title");
```

Answer (score 0):

The texts in the types are hard-coded and bound to the libraries bundle. Therefore you can not change them. The only approach to do that would be to inherit from a UI5 type and extend it to your needs.

Fortunately you can always use the Control events [validationError](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#event:validationError) and [validationSuccess](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#event:validationSuccess) to handle the validation yourself and use your own texts there.